# Making a Script that deletes its own folder when it finishes

Tags: python, path, directory, delete-directory

Is it possible to make a script delete its own folder? clearly there are some issues here but I feel like it might be possible.

Essentially what i'm trying to create is a script that once it's finished doing it's thing that will delete it's own folder and a few other files. But I'm mainly having an issue with trying to tell it to delete itself as a method of closing itself.

As a final action or in a sense telling the pc to do one more action after its closed itself

**Any help would be greatly appreciated** :)

Tltr;can an application can tell windows to do a command after it close's it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The script will be loaded into memory when it runs, so it can delete its parent directory (and therefore itself) directly from the script without any issues. Just use `shutil.rmtree` rather than `os.rmdir`, because `os.rmdir` can't remove a directory that isn't empty.

Here's a one-liner that will do it (be careful running this in a directory with stuff you don't want deleted!)
`shutil.rmtree(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))`

Comment: So if this was the path i was trying to delete: 

        C:\Users\SpanjerX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Test1\SelfDeleter.exe

||||||would i just do it like this: 

shutil.rmtree(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(C:\Users\SpanjerX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Test1)))

Comment: @SpanjerRyan No, just paste it literally as I did above. `__file__` is automatically set by Python as the path to the script being executed. So no matter what directory you put the script in, it'll end up deleting that directory when you run it.

Comment: O ok thank you I was 50 50 if that's how it worked, Btw thanks alot I really do appreciate the help

Comment: Ok so it seems like shutil.rmtree(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))   is only actually deleting the script it self rather then deleting the folder it's in.

Comment: Hmm, try having the script print out what it's going to delete instead of actually deleting it. `os.path.dirname` should guarantee that the directory gets deleted, not the file.

Comment: It seems that it's having issues with deleteing a folder thats in use, i ran the debugger on it in Wing IDE and it said this: WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\SpanjerX\\Videos\\File Deleter'

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/SyRbd52.png

Comment: Ah, Linux will let you do this, so I assumed (incorrectly, apparently) that Windows would, too.

Comment: You might be able to work around the issue by changing the working directory of the script prior to doing the delete, using `os.chdir`.

Comment: That actually sounds like it'd work i was curious if that was possible while the program was running, How would i go about changing it's directory from lets say C:\Users\SpanjerX\Videos\File Deleter to Libraries\Videos

Comment: `os.chdir("C:\\Libraries\\Videos")` You can use relative paths, too: `os.chdir("..\\Some\\Path")`

Answer (score 1):

You mean it would delete the entire folder, including the script itself?

Why not invoke the script with a `cmd` or `batch` file (on Windows; `bash` script on *nix) that would first execute the script, and then do whatever cleanup you want to do afterwards? The wrapper file could live in another directory so it would not also get deleted.

Comment: Yep I want it to delete itself and the folder that it's residing in.

Ty for the help ill try that out